# Custom CSV Parser

Tags: python, parsing, csv, python-3.x

**Would it be bad form to read/write a csv file from scratch, instead of using the csv module?**

I have a file where each line represents a list of parameters for a file operation:

```
"time", "old path", "new path", "metadata1", "metadata2" ...
"time", "old path", "new path", "metadata1", "metadata2" ...
```

I wrote some methods that let me convert between a string of `'"value", "value", "value"'` and a list of `[value, value, value]`

```
def get_csv(iterable):
    "Return iterable as a string of comma-separated-values"
    return ', '.join('"{}"'.format(str(i)) for i in iterable)

def get_list(string):
    "Return a list from a string of comma-separated-values"
    # remove first/last parantheses and separate by ", "
    return string[1:-1].split('", "')
```

and I put it all together in a class

```
class LogParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.feed = []

    def read(self, fp):
        "Parse log feed from a csv file"
        with open(fp, 'r') as csvfile:
            for line in csvfile:
                self.feed.append(get_list(line.strip()))

    def write(self, fp):
        "Write log feed to a csv file"
        with open(fp, 'w') as csvfile:
            for entry in self.feed:
                csvfile.write(get_csv(entry) + '\n')

    def update(self, entry, fp):
        "Update entry to feed and append entry to a csv file, on a new line"
        with open(fp, 'a') as csvfile:
            csvfile.write(get_csv(entry) + '\n')
        self.feed.append(entry)

    def search(self, query):
        ## return any lines in self.feed that match the query
        pass
```

Each time I update the feed with a list, it updates the file as well, without having to rewrite the entire file every time.

This is so that I can sort files using a script, and record the parameters after each operation.  Something like:

```
logger = LogParser()

def sortfiles(sourcedir):
    for filename in os.listdir(sourcedir):
        old_path = os.path.join(sourcedir, filename)
        metadata1 = # something used to sort the file
        metadata2 = # something else used to sort the file
        new_path = # determine the new path using metadata
        time = # get the time

        try:
            os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        except SomeError:
            raise('Something went wrong when trying to move the file!') 
        else:
            logger.update([time, old_path, new_path, metadata1, metadata2])
```

This works, but is there anything wrong with this approach?  Would there be a benefit if I  used the csv module instead?

Comment: Not bad form, but probably pointless.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of using the csv module (among other things, I'm sure) are:

- More testing: other people and lots of developers are using this code, and (hopefully), reporting and fixing bugs.
- You wouldn't have to write all this code

In programming in general, if open, tested, popular and supported libraries already do what you need, why not save yourself the effort and put that effort into other parts of your code?